# Discord.py on_message() repeating execution

Tags: python, events, discord, repeat

Long time user, first time poster. :-)

I'm using discord.py==1.7.2. I have a probably complicated bot that I have been hacking out through trial and error (super sketchy documentation as far as I can tell and maybe I don't really understand the Discord concept), but I am seeing some super strange behavior in the on_message() event. After having everything working like I wanted, I noticed an issue and simply wanted to check a value when the on_message() event was executed. I printed it to the chat. I then noticed it was printed repeatedly, non-stop to the chat until I killed the bot. Am I missing something here? My expectation is that the event on_message() runs when a user enters something and presses enter and then stops. Is this wrong? Code:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):

    if len(message.content) < 5:
        return

    await message.channel.send('wtf')
```

If I type anything below 5 chars, nothing happens. If I type "12345", the chaos begins.. it spits out 5 lines of "wtf" and then 4 "wtf"s every few seconds until I kill the bot. Is this happening for everyone? Or did I break it somewhere else? Super confused.

Thanks for any help!!!

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your event is `on_message`, and you are sending a message inside this event, which then triggers the event again, and then sends a message again and so on, in a loop.

you should check the sender of the message, if its the bot, then return.
like so,

```py
#... other code
@bot.event
async def on_message(message: Message):
    if message.author.bot: #if message's author is a bot, then ignore it.
        return
    #... rest of your on_message()
```

Comment: Ahh,, ffs.. I hate programming and my brain sometimes lol. That makes sense :-D Thank you for the quick help!!! I have this in other places but didn't think about it in this place / context. Really appreciate your help and this space for being able to ask questions and people helping. Really awesome.

Comment: @ja-dev the thing is, now that i think about it a bit more, i'm kinda confused too now... since 'wtf''s length is in fact less than 5, so it shouldnt trigger this event more than once :/  but regardless im glad your code works now.

Comment: The text entered was actually "12345" and not "wtf". :-) All good lol. Programming is such a fun punch to the brain.